# Combine multiple atom/electron apps

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, electron

Is there a way to load an electron app inside another electron app?
I would like to have the effect of an host electron app and multiple electron apps inside iframes.
The concept is to have multiple electron apps as widgets installable through a main electron app. For example I want to have one window where
you can see a twitter client app and facebook messenger app as tabs of a main window. It doesn't matter if size of the app gets big.

Comment: Would you be willing to share a bit more about what you are trying to achieve? Electron apps tend to be quite large so embedding one app within another could produce quite a large install base.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **windows** 'cause at the end you just need html,css and some js to do widgets like show twitter, so prepare a function to pass the html directory of the page dynamically.

Otherwise if you prefer call exactly another app you can make a function for call the path of the app that you want  using [childprocess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)